# Read deserialized file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I need to regain Latitude and Longitude addresses using the Google Maps API and C #. I got this data using dynamic. Follows the code:

```
public static dynamic GEOCodeAddress(String EnderecoCompleto)
{
    var endereco = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false", EnderecoCompleto.Replace(" ", "+"));
    var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(endereco);
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(result);
}
```

I obtained the following returns:

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Condomínio do Edif Shopping Cent Resende",
               "short_name" : "Condomínio do Edif Shopping Cent Resende",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "369",
               "short_name" : "369",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Avenida Saturnino Braga",
               "short_name" : "Av. Saturnino Braga",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Primeiro",
               "short_name" : "Primeiro",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Resende",
               "short_name" : "Resende",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Resende",
               "short_name" : "Resende",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rio de Janeiro",
               "short_name" : "RJ",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brasil",
               "short_name" : "BR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "27511300",
               "short_name" : "27511300",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Condomínio do Edif Shopping Cent Resende - Avenida Saturnino Braga, 369 - Primeiro, Resende - RJ, 27511-300, Brasil",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               **"lat" : -22.4663045,
               "lng" : -44.4512964**
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -22.4649555197085,
                  "lng" : -44.4499474197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -22.4676534802915,
                  "lng" : -44.45264538029149
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJHTTnrJZ-ngARWHOfZ1DmWGM",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The method call is made as follows:

```
dynamic retorno = GEOCodeAddress("Avenida Saturnino Braga, 369 centro, resende - rj");
```

I need to capture the values in bold.

My question is: How can I retrieve this data using the C # language and convert them in type String ???

I thank you all for your help and I apologize for my simple English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English. Please edit it into English, and format the JSON more readably. (And don't shout in the title...)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Json.NET as Json parser (more reliable than the native .Net implementation). Just grab the package through NuGet.

Then try to use something like 'Dictionary<string,object>' instead of 'dynamic'.
This would make it easier to access the object. 
Or just leave out the target type. then Json.NET will return a JObject type, which can also be accessed through indexers.

The nicest way tho, would be to create a class with that structure and deserialize your JSON into that using Json.NET. Then you would have nice lists/Properties to access.

Comment: How would the implementation using Json.NET? I did some tests and it still fails. Dictionary I also never worked. Would you help me?